# How to have img{float-left;} shrink width p element next to it?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` containing an `<img>`, a `<h2>` and a `<p>`. The left half of the `<div>` should be exactly filled with the img and I want the `<h2>` and `<p>` in the right half.

The problem is: the floating `<img>` doesn't shrink the width of the `<p>` so the `padding-left` is behind the `<img>`, causing `<p>`'s text to be too tight against the `<img>`.

How can I resolve this? I created a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/powcfyjL/) The screenshot of it below illustrates better what I mean.
[image]

The html is

```
<div class='featured left'>
    <img src='http://www.spss-tutorials.com/img/turtle-left.png'>
    <h2 class='ol'><a href="#">Why I love my Turtle!</a></h2>
    <p>My turtle, Harry Turtle, is simply the friendliest and most clever turtle in the world!
      <a href='http://www.dumpert.nl/mediabase/2013731/8ff0c33d/harry_turtle.html'>
Read more.</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

and the CSS is

```
div{
display:table;
margin:1.5em auto 0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid #0a93cd;
border-radius:.5em;
width:50em;
padding:0;
}

div h2{
margin:0;
padding:.1em 0 .1em .5em;
padding:0 0 0.1em .5em;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid #0a93cd;
border-width:0px 0 1px 0 ;
background:#0a93cd;
 }

div h2 a{
color:#0a93cd;
color:#fff;
font:normal .8em arial;
font:normal 1em arial;
font:bold .8em arial;
}

div h2 a:hover{
color:#00006d;
}

div.top img{
width:100%;
display:block;
border-bottom:1px solid #0a93cd;
}

div.left img{
width:50%;
float:left;
border-right:2px solid #0a93cd;
}

div.right img{
width:50%;
float:right;
border-bottom:1px solid #0a93cd;
}

div p{padding:.5em 1em .5em 1em;}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. And does the padding need to be in em units?

Comment: Uh... doesn't the jsfiddle qualify as a MCVE?

Comment: Code should always be in your question first. Sites like jsFiddle or jsbin should *supplement* the code in your question, never be the sole source of it. What happens if they ever are down or go away?

Comment: Also, don't use jsFiddle but use a native SO snippet - @j08691 that solves the issue of when-those-sites-go-down.

Answer (score 2):

Add a margin to your image to push to the side **or** make you `p` a floating element as well (although this might make the layout harder to control).

```
img { margin-right: 10px; }
```

Your image is not set set to `float: left;` in your current code, though.

The reason you are seeing this is because an element that is `floating` does not behave like a standard `block` element anymore. It's size (and *blockiness*) only pushes against the contents of other blocks. The actual blocks will just ignore the element (unless that block is floating as well). It's quirky, but it does make sense. Floating elements therefore need to give their own margin to push away more of the content of regular blocks.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="So, this is an image." />
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</p>
```

Comment: @RubenGeert Waw that was a stupid mistake. Good edit mate!

Comment: I like this answer, but applying it to the OP's original code causes the header to no longer be centered.  Hard to tell with 10px margin, but pretty obvious with a 50px margin:  https://jsfiddle.net/bayttyn6/

Comment: Of course. `margin-right` on the `img`. Retrospectively, I'd perhaps better not display the `img` as a block but that will cause some other problems... Thx a lot anyway!

Comment: @RickHitchcock True, but the alternative is using `text-indent` on the header, actually. But that's not a very nice alternative tbh. Otherwise there will be some more refactoring for this to work.

Comment: @RickHitchcock I know, that's what I meant. The better solution is refactoring the DOM to keep in mind this side-effect of `float`ers, but I'm thinking that's a bit beyond the scope of the question. Cheers

Comment: @RickHitchcock: by "header" you refer to the `h2`? The sizes in the fiddle will probably be the actual sizes (in em, not px) that I'll use. If `h2` *looks* centered but isn't exactly, then I can't really be bothered.

Comment: Yes, a 10px margin means the `h2` is off-center by 5px, which is barely noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Add this style:

```
div p {
  display: table;
}
```

That seems to create a new line box context, which solves the problem.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7aa98wst/)

Comment: Nice one too! I'm going to try both suggested answers in the actual code and see which one will float up (pun intended) as the winner.